# What is the "right" way to do this with Core Data (updating multiple entities)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm new to Core Data. I have two entities: `USER` and `IOU`.

```
// User.h
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<NSManagedObject *> *ious;

// Iou.h
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber *amount;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *iouDescription;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) User *user;
```

In a view controller, I use a predicate to fetch the ious belonging to a user and then I use that to fetch the user for its name. I then display that user's name along with her list of ious.

```
// PersonViewController.m
// Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Iou"];

// Predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",   @"user.name", self.userName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Execute fetch request
NSError *error = nil;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

Iou *iou = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.lastObject;
self.user = iou.user;
```

Next, my customers can tap on an IOU and edit both the IOU and the user.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Iou *iou = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    personEditViewController.user = self.user;
    personEditViewController.iou = iou;
    personEditViewController.managedContext = self.managedContext;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:personEditViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Here is how I am editing both the `USER` entity and the `IOU` entity.

```
// PersonEditViewController.m
self.user.name = self.nameField.text;

// Description
self.iou.iouDescription = self.descriptionField.text;

// Date
UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)self.dateField.inputView;
self.iou.date = datePicker.date;

// Save
NSError *error;
[self.iou.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to work with a `UITableView`. If I **ONLY** change IOU attributes, I get the right behavior. I get `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove`; however, if I also update the USER, I get `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete`. If I restart, the data looks fine so it's only happening in the view.

I searched through some SO questions but I still don't get it. What's a simple pattern to use so it will always work every time.

I considered not using `NSFetchedResultsController` and relying on good old `NSArray` with a `UITableView`. In that case, every time I CRUD a record, it will refetch the records from DB and I'll use the `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`.

Comment: where do you create the  personEditViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you amend the `name` property of the `User` object, it will no longer match the predicate - so the FRC will trigger the delete to remove the corresponding row in the table view.  (Note that you might expect all the other rows to be deleted, since they also no longer satisfy the predicate, but the FRC only re-evaluates those `IOU`s which have been updated).

If you want to avoid this, then amend your fetch results controller code to first fetch the `User` object(s) that match the predicate, then amend the FRC predicate to test whether the `IOU` belongs to any of those users:

```
// PersonViewController.m
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *userFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",   @"name", self.userName];
userFetchRequest.predicate = userPredicate;
NSArray *matchingUsers = [self.managedContext executeFetchRequest:userFetchRequest error:&error];
// Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Iou"];

// Predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@",   @"user", matchingUsers];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Execute fetch request
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

Iou *iou = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.lastObject;
self.user = iou.user;
```

Since the FRC's predicate is based on the `User` object itself, not any of its attributes, you can amend those attributes without causing its `IOU`s to fail to satisfy the FRC's predicate.

Comment: Thank you! It works. The only missing part of your code is to set the userPredicate to userFetchRequest but I assumed that was the case.

Comment: Yes - forgive the omission.  I'll update the answer when back at my desk.